# Ideals of $ord$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $R = R_p = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}\ |\ ord_p(x)\geq0\}$, which is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> (a) Show that the only nonzero ideals of $R$ are the principal ideals $(p^e)$ for $e\geq0$, so that $R$ is a PID.
>
> (b) Show that every nonzero $x \in R$ can be uniquely expressed as $x=up^e$ with $u$ a unit of $R$ and $e\geq0$. Deduce that $R$ is a unique factorization domain with only one irreducible (up to associates), namely $p$.
>
> (c) Can you generalise this to construct UFDs with exactly two irreducibles (up to associates)? Exactly $n$?

I have very little idea how to do parts a and b. And do not understand part c.

For (a) R is a PID by definition if I prove the statement. I said let I be an ideal of R. How do I prove it is principal?

For (b) Write $x= p^e \frac{a}{b}$ Need to show $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\;x\in R_p\;$ is a unit iff $\;ord_p(x)=0\;$ , and from  here that if we define

$\;M:=\{x\in R_p\;;\;ord_p(x)>0\}\;$ , then $\;M\le R_p\;$ and $\;R_p\setminus M\;$ is the set of all units in $\;R_p\;$ ,

from which it follows that $\;R_p\;$ is a local ring (in fact, a local domain) and $\;M\;$ is its unique maximal ideal.

Now, observe that

$$x\in M\implies x=p^ex'\;,\;\;x'\in R_p\setminus M\implies x\in\langle p^e\rangle$$

Comment: What about part (b). The deduce bit I know how to do, but not sure about the bit before. I know $ord_(x)=1$ iff x is irreducible .

Comment: I think it is there: if $\;f\ge e\;$ , then $$p^ex'=p^fx''\implies x'=p^{f-e}x''\stackrel{x'\;\text{is a unit}}\implies f-e=0\implies\;\text{also}\;x'=x''$$

Comment: How do I get $e≥0$? for both parts? Is it to do with being integers?

Comment: All the elements in $\;R_p\;$ have non negative power pf $\;p\;$ by definition.

Comment: Ofcourse thanks. What is part c asking?

Comment: In the present case, and in any case of commutative local ring, you get one unique irreducible up to associates (namely, $\,p\,$) ,and they ask you whether you can generalize this process to have two or $\;n\;$ irreducibles up to associates. For me the answer is very simple: no, I can't..

Comment: This questions drags on too much. Maybe you need to use the fact there can be as many units as you want?

Comment: @George Perhaps, yet the units are exactly the elements in the (local) ring that don't belong to the (unique) maximal ideal, so I can't see how can that be under our control.

Comment: There are infinitely many primes of any use? And we know $ord_p(x)=1$ iff $x$ is irreducible. Write $x=ab, so 1=ord_p(x)=ord_p(a)+ord_p(b)$ but $a,b$ can only be $0$ or $1$? In general take a as 1 and the rest as 0

Comment: @George Yes, but how is that related to the above?

Comment: I think part (b) is key but cannot see where to use it

Comment: Also what do you mean by local ring/domain? I have come across the terms PID, euclidean domain, associates only.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you. But for part (a) how does the last implication follow. Also why is the majority of the work of part (b) in part (a). Is it relevant there?

Comment: I do not see how part (a) is answered. Thanks for part(b) - I have now completed that

Comment: @George, since $\;M=\langle\,p\,\rangle\;$, all the other ideals must be of the form $\;\langle\,p^e\,\rangle\;$ since any ideal is contained in a maximal one and there is only one such maximal ideal here. This also follows from (b).

Comment: Thanks, is the answer to part (c) no?

Comment: @George For (c) my answer is "No, I can't". Perhaps it is possible, though.

Comment: Any reason why you think no?

Comment: In fact I think it may be possible @George , I just don't know how to achieve that.